# Find transformations between cameras using world coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, homography

I have a setup of two cameras (with the same intrinsic matrix) that captures a static scene.
Additional data I have:

- couples of N matching points in world coordinates in each camera system: {(xi,yi,zi), (Xi,Yi,Zi)}.
- couples of N matching points in each image system: {(ui,vi), (Ui,Vi)}.

My question is: How can I calculate rotation matrix (R) and translation vector (t) between the cameras, using the data above?

I have tried the python opencv function cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() that gets 4 couples of matching points in image system ({(ui,vi), (Ui,Vi)}), but it returns rotation matrix only. Is it the right thing to do? If so, how can I find t as well?

Thanks!

Gavriel

Answer (score 0):

If you have >= 3 world-image point correspondences in each view you can use solvePnP to recover the pose of each camera with respect to the world.

See, for example [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/).